# Label Picker SwiftUI not updating in iOS14

Tags: swiftui, picker, ios14

```
Section(header: Text("Title")) {
                Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("label")) {
                    if let datos = viewModel.wcenterListData{
                        ForEach(datos.list){ item in
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
            }
```

Im trying to change selection but default label still on screen, this problem is only in iOS14 version.

As you can see in the image, the 2rd item is selected but is not showed in the "button", still showing the word "label"

[image: pickerimage]

Comment: exchange `Text("label")` with `Text(selection)`